# Does TCP_NODELAY disable auto corking?

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming

Does setting TCP_NODELAY prevent auto corking? Is there a way to turn off auto corking on a per socket basis?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich No. That is about explicit TCP_CORK. Autocorking is done when TCP_CORK isn't specified but the kernel detect rapid writes before the skbuf has left and holds up following outbound packets, but the documentation is a little fuzzy.

Comment: Are you on Linux or macOS? Do you have any code you've tried already?

Comment: @drewster Take a look at the tags. OP is asking about Linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27139807/what-is-tcp-autocorking-tcp-automatic-corking) Stack Overflow post on what autocorking is, we can see:

> ...so it would still work even when `TCP_NODELAY` option is set.

Other than that, we have [this](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/20140208091944.GB16336@glanzmann.de/) conversation which states:

> Lets wait the end of 3.14 dev cycle before considering this patch.

So, to answer your original question, setting `TCP_NODELAY` does *not* prevent autocorking. As of turning off autocorking, [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434483/set-so-tcp-nodelay-disabling-the-nagle-algorithm) post on Unix might help you.

> Short answer: `tcp_nagle_check()` in `net_ipv4_tcp_output.c`

Comment: I don't undersand how that bottom link says anything about turning aotucork off. And the link it goes to doesn't say much about disabling it either. I find it rather obnoxious that such potentially performance impacting change could be installed with no per socket way to disable it.